# What would a beach look like if prolonged exposure to humans made the sand change color?

Tags: urban-fantasy, colors

So one of the supernatural elements in my urban fantasy story is a system of "aura-syncing" that explains how various supernatural abilities extend to one's clothes and belongings. A full explanation can be found [here.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111135/double-checking-my-worlds-rules-for-making-magic-extend-to-clothes)

Tl;dr: Every human projects an invisible aura 3 inches from their body, and any solid object that spends 5 minutes completely encased in this aura becomes "synced" to that aura and is treated as a part of their body for the purpose of various abilities as long as it's at least partially within their aura when that ability is used. The aura an object is synced to will be changed again the next time it spends 5 minutes encased in a new aura.

Now, the main character is one of a few people on Earth who has the ability to *see* these auras. When he uses this ability, the entire world turns pure white with these sort of cell-shaded borders, and the only things that have any color are human auras and any objects that have been synced to an aura. Every person's aura actually has a color assigned to it, which can be absolutely anything except white (or any color too close to white for the average human eye to distinguish), though darker colors are rarer. And the main character will see any synced objects as being the same color as the aura of the person it's synced to.

Now, the fact that this applies even to the tiniest particles or grains of sand is a pretty crucial plot point, and it got me to start imagining what a beach would look like in this "aura vision", with every single grain of sand a human's ever sat near for five minutes being imprinted with that human's unique color.

Right away it sounds like a really striking image, with a technicolor pattern of human bodies imprinted into the sand from all the beachgoers lying down on it, slowly eroded by the sand being kicked around until the colors mix together, only to all be re-imprinted again. But I was wondering if there'd be anything else to the picture.

***Is there anything about how sand moves and scatters on a beach that would cause other patterns to emerge, or anything else that would affect what my protagonist would see?***

Comment: There are currently 7.5 billion people on earth. There are no 7.5 billion colors all distinguishible from each other by the human eye.

Comment: Also, the 'partially' part is a tricky one (I haven't read it in your original post, which is why I comment here). What would you do about some really large objects? Smoke a cigarette leaning on a wall, whole house turns blue? What if someone joins you and you both touch the wall for five minutes? Just stroll along the road, whole sidewalk turns red? You wrote something about this power only working within the aura itself for certain objects, I think you really need a clear distinction, and logical reason if you create any exception (balancing is not a logical reason).

Comment: @Otto Abnormalverbraucher It’s only partial when the object has already been synced. If you have a sword, it’s treated as part of you as long as your aura is touching it, but that’s only after you held the whole thing against you and inside your aura for 5 minutes. You can’t sync any solid object that is too large to encase in your aura, though you could sync individual parts of it like planks of wood or screws.

Comment: I see, so you cannot sync a 3m halberd because it doesn't fit into your aura, ever. Or a (kinda) large mech suit or whatever other suit or weapon doesn't fit. That makes sense.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Yep, unfortunately, halberds can't be used with those powers. At least not by humans, that is.

Comment: Is there any limit to how long an object not in an aura remains synced for?  (i.e. if a grain of sand was synced 1,000 years ago, then washed into the ocean, would it still be synced today?)  And, what happens to a synced stone that is worn down and turns into sand - is that sand all synced to the person the stone was?

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Have a screw connection about midway down the haft, and a wire/chain/rope to keep the parts as "one item", then keep both of the 4ft halves within your aura for 5 minutes?  Then screw it back together already synced.

Comment: @Chronocidal There's no time limit, but during the story, by the time the main character sees this sight, the magic has only been around for at most half a year. As for when the synced object is worn down, I figure that it has significantly increased resistance to wear and tear, but once it does wear or crack or break or in any other way cease to be one whole piece, the syncing is stopped.

Comment: @Chronocidal I'd assume a staff weapon relies heavily on the wood used, which goes for spears, halberds, pikes, quarterstaves and so on, and it is ill advise to break the wood apart in order to set it back together as you unintentionally create a weak spot. It massively reduces the quality of the weapon if not making it entirely useless.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Once synced, can you use supernatural powers to reinforce it and prevent the weakness?  Or, just use a slightly shorter haft:  reaching my arms above my head, I would have enough reach to sync a halberd of about 8ft (2.5m) - considering that historically they were typically about 5ft (1.5m ) that's still quite excessive.

Answer (score 6):

I remember you original question --- very interesting!

As for the sands of the shore, I honestly don't think the effects will be quite as spectacular as you might be hoping.

Some possibilities:

1. **Ideal situation** is where there is a calm sea and no breeze to speak of all on a warm day that is a holiday during beach season. This will give you maximum number of people with a minimum of sand movement. If your aura-sighted person knows what colour, hue and saturation to look for, she will be confronted by thousands of latent impressions. The people that stayed (in one place) the longest and were the last to leave, will naturally leave behind the most pristine impressions. She might be able to see a more saturated area that represents the torso with perhaps smaller patches where the head and arms and feet rested. Other impressions will be less clear: if someone laid on the sand for a couple hours, relatively late in the afternoon, and then left, chances are good his impression will be at least somewhat disturbed. People running might churn up portions of the impression, but she should still be able to make out a blobby outline at least.
2. **Less Than Ideal Situation** is weather conditions as above, but the person in question lay on the beach during the morning and then got up to leave around noon when once the place became too crowded. Chances are very good her colour sand will be churned up and locally scattered. Perhaps built into a sand castle along with other people's sand who were lying nearby. Our aura-sighted girl will find it very difficult to determine what the actual colour scheme is. She might be able to get a general description like "greenish", but it will mixed in a three (or actually four) dimensional cloud of other colours and saturations.
3. **Least Ideal Situation** is where an early morning person lay on a very popular spot that was eventually taken over several times during the day and also got churned up, built into sand castles, which got dashed down and scattered, and then smoothed over again.

Note also that for each of these ideal situations, our aura-sighted girl will have to contend with particles that have been synched on the days and weeks previous.

1. **Very Likely Situation** is where our girl will have to contend with normal seaside weather. Beaches are very labile. They don't stay in one place. The sands are constantly shifting as winds blow them this way and that. Tides cause sand to be heaped up and drawn away again. If she takes a look at the beach on a windy day after the tide goes out again, she'll be confronted not only by the churned up and commingled colours of the day and the days previous, but also the colours of sands that the winds have exposed from higher up and the sands that the waters have deposited on the beach. The longer she delays, the more the beach will evolve and obscure any impression she might have been able to make out.
2. **Worst Case Scenario** is of course that her investigation has been hampered by very bad weather. Hurricane Sandy is about to visit the Big Pomegranate and the beach is inaccessible. By the time our aura-sighted girl can get out there, there is simply no beach. All the synched sand has been washed out to sea. Looking out into the water itself will be no help, as her sight will be blurred by all the water molecules that have become synched to hundreds of millions of people all across the eastern US whose (treated) piss & bath water has made it out to sea...

PS: you can buy coloured sands in most any craft shop. Buy a few different kinds and mix em up in a jar. See for yourself what our girl will see!

PPS: *EDIT* --- I'd imagine that even the very best case scenario impression will look something like a luminol image:

http://truejustice.org/ee/images/perugia/frontpage113/11355.jpg

And being a popular beach, image upon image upon image.

Answer (score 0):

A **three inch radius** and **five minute exposure** time required for aura syncing means that the vast majority of beach sand would **stay sand colored**.  Only on popular beaches in places like California, Florida and Hawaii where lots of people go and lay in the sun would you see colored blotches of sand.

The protagonist would see human-sized stripes of sand where people lay.  After the people get up and leave, these stripes would eventually get smudged (during the night, during weekdays when there are fewer sun worshipers, etc).

High tides, wind and storms would also mix the surface sand.  Over the long term, you'd get a smudgy mixture of white and sand.

Remember, though: due to the **three inch radius** and **five minute exposure** time required for aura syncing, the vast majority of sandy beaches would just stay sand colored, since so many people go to the beach and play (in the surf, on the sand, etc) instead of just laying there.

Comment: Never been downy oshun, hon? Rehobeth and Ocean City get pretty crowded, too!

Comment: @elemtilas the key phrase is "where lots of people go and lay in the sun".  There are a lot of beaches where very few people go.

Comment: Of course! Just wasn't sure if there was some "warm sunny" bias going on. ;) But yeah, there are plenty of empty beaches out there! Alert, NU comes to mind immediately...